Node doesn't see certificate leaf_signature
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
I got this error while running npx create-react-app ./ or other else command using **npm **install.
I have had never before such an error.
Should i set environmental variable or something? I'm working on Windows.
Turning of firewall woTurning of firewall works, but i don't want to do it every time.rks, but i don't want to do it every time.

It's the last ESET update:
https://forum.eset.com/topic/40702-eset-ssl-protection-produces-an-invalid-certificate-chain-for-nodejs-apps/
You can fix it temporarily and ESET will fix it permanently with an update. So whatever you do, you should undo it later.
Quick fix:

Go to Network Setting / Advanced Settings (this might differ)
SSL/TLS
Edit on Application Scan Rules
Add Node (node.exe) as an exception. Select "ignore"

You could also disable SSL entirely on ESET, but is better to just disable what has the issue. Just remember to re-enable it later, once ESET rolls out the fix-update.
There are other ways to fix it temporarily (waiting for ESET official update):

Setup > Web access protection > Disable HTTPS traffic scanning
Download the new update (1475), which should fix the issue (needs the pre-release update enabled in settings)


It might be related to the ESET Antivirus update if you use ESET.
See the forum post here: https://forum.eset.com/topic/40702-eset-ssl-protection-produces-an-invalid-certificate-chain-for-nodejs-apps/
There's various attempts to work around it in the post but I'm not having much joy myself.
